# How to activate javascript code on form validation with php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

How to activate javascript code on form validation.

I am running form validation on a combined (visually) login/register form. The login form is displayed by default and the register form is displayed when a user clicks a button and the following js code is run

```
var card = document.getElementById("card");
      function openRegister() {
        card.style.transform = "rotateY(-180deg)";
      }
      function openLogin() {
        card.style.transform = "rotateY(0deg)";
      }
```

Which all works fine, the problem comes when I run the form validation using php. The error reporting works, and the error messages displayed in the correct location. So, error message for the login form is displayed in a div with a class of card-front, and the registration form error is in a div with a class of card-back.

So the system works fine when the user uses the login page, which is shown by default, the issue arises when the user uses the register form because the header(“location:loginRegForm.php”) shows the default login form. If the button is clicked to show the register form the correct error message is displayed.

So, I need a way of triggering the above js code so if there is an error when using the register form the registration form is shown not the default login form.
I have struggled with this for a few days so I would be grateful for any pointers

Comment: I would recommend submitting the forms using Ajax. That way it will submit the form in the background, without changing the view/page in any way.

Comment: @M. Eriksson Thanks I will look into using Ajax

Comment: "I need a way of triggering the above js code" - what have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why is this question tagged with CSS and PHP, but does not contain any such code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the error via $_SESSION or query parameter.

```
header("location:loginRegForm.php?regError=Custom errror message")
```

and then via javascript show the register form, es:

```
<script>
  if(document.location.href.indexOf('regError') > -1) {
     openRegister();
     var querystring = document.location.href.split('?').pop().split('&');
     for(var qs, qsi = 0; qsi < querystring.length; qsi++) {
       qs = querystring[qsi].split('=');
       if(qs[0] === 'errorMsg') {
          document.queryString('.regErrorBlock').innerText = qs[1];
          document.queryString('.regErrorBlock').style.display = 'block';
          break;
       }
     }
  }
</script>
```

inside the register form add this block to show the error

```
<div class="regErrorBlock" style="display:none"></div>
```

Comment: @ Just one question if I may, the code works perfectly to display the correct form but is does not show the error message. This is the code I am using, is it possible to add the error message this why? Thanks
header("location: ../loginRegForm.php?showRegForm=1?error=usernameoremailtaken");

Comment: Sure, you can do that, the second parameter should be passed as & maybe it's easier to echo it inside the register form directly

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer my question and posting both solutions. Very much appreciated